# How to save a excel file to users download path in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, fileoutputstream

In my project I will create an `ExcelWorkBook` and write some data into that workbook.
After writing it I want it to save to the users download path, so have tried the following code:

```
XSSFWorkbook hwb=new XSSFWorkbook();  
XSSFSheet sheet =  hwb.createSheet("Exam Marks Entry");
//writing data to workbook

//then targeting users download path as follows
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
File file = new File(home+"/Downloads/"+mainDisplayDto.getClassName()+" "+mainDisplayDto.getExamName()+".xlsx");

FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(file);  
hwb.write(fileOut);
```

The above code works(saves workbook to download path) only when the application is local, but it does not work when the application is on **VPS**.

**How can I save it to the users systems downloads folder when the application is not ran locally?**

**My problem will also be solved, if after writing the data to workbook I can  open the excel file in the system so that user will save wherever they want.**

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: With a web server and a web browser?

Comment: web server its a linux server(VPS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved with help of @Jai Prakash suggestion  and changing my ajax call and some of my java code please look at the code

**ajax call:**

```
      $(document).on("click","#downlodMarksSheet",function(event){
            var examCatId=$("#meExamMainEV").val();     
            var classId=$(".mainContainer #meClass").val();  
            var secId=$(".mainContainer #sectionId").val() ;
            var stringFromDate=$(".mainContainer #FromDate").val();
            var stringToDate=$(".mainContainer #ToDate").val();
            var url = contextPath+"/excel/exportExcel/"+classId+"/"+secId+"/"+examCatId+"/"+stringFromDate.replace(/\//g, "-")+"/"+stringToDate.replace(/\//g, "-");
            window.location.href=url;
        });

**java code :**

@GetMapping(value = "/exportExcel/{classId}/{secId}/{examCatId}/{stringFromDate}/{stringToDate}")
    public HttpServletResponse updateStudentGeneralDetailss(@PathVariable("classId") int classId,
            @PathVariable("secId") int secId,@PathVariable("examCatId") int examCatId,
            @PathVariable("stringFromDate") String stringFromDate,
            @PathVariable("stringToDate") String stringToDate,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

        try { 



            String filename="";
            XSSFWorkbook hwb=new XSSFWorkbook();  
            XSSFSheet sheet =  hwb.createSheet("Exam Marks Entry");  
            XSSFRow subsHead=   sheet.createRow(0);
            subsHead.createCell(1).setCellValue("");
            XSSFRow subSubsIdsHead=   sheet.createRow(1);
            XSSFRow subSubs=   sheet.createRow(2);



            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

            ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();


            XSSFColor myColor = new XSSFColor(Color.YELLOW);

            XSSFCellStyle style = hwb.createCellStyle();  
            style.setAlignment(XSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
            style.setVerticalAlignment(XSSFCellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
            style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());

            style.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            style.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
            style.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            style.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
            style.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            style.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
            style.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            style.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());  



                ExmaExportDTO mainDisplayDto  = service.getExamPartten(examCatId, classId, secId,stringFromDate.replaceAll("-", "/"),stringToDate.replaceAll("-", "/"));

            List<ExamStudentMarksDisplaySubjectsDTO> subjects=  mainDisplayDto.getSubjectsList();
            int i=2;
            int formCol=2;
            int subsubCol=2;

            sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,0,1));
            sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,1,0,1));

            Cell cel=subSubs.createCell(0); 
            cel.setCellStyle(style);  
            cel.setCellValue("Student Ids");

            Cell cel1=subSubs.createCell(1);
            cel1.setCellStyle(style);  
            cel1.setCellValue("Student Name");

            /*iterating subjects*/
            for(ExamStudentMarksDisplaySubjectsDTO subObj : subjects)
            {  
                Cell cell=subsHead.createCell(formCol);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                cell.setCellValue(subObj.getSubjectName());;
                List<ExamStudentMarksDisplaySubjectsSubCatDTO> subSubj=subObj.getSubCatMarks();

                int subSubjLen=subSubj.size(); 

                int toCol=formCol+subSubjLen;

                sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,formCol,toCol-1));

                for(ExamStudentMarksDisplaySubjectsSubCatDTO subsubObj :subSubj)
                {
                    Cell cell1=subSubsIdsHead.createCell(subsubCol);
                    cell1.setCellStyle(style);
                    cell1.setCellValue(subsubObj.getExmSubjectSubCategory());
                    Cell cell2=subSubs.createCell(subsubCol);
                    cell2.setCellStyle(style);  
                    cell2.setCellValue(subsubObj.getSubCatName()+"("+subsubObj.getSubCatMaxMarks()+")");
                    subsubCol++;
                }

                formCol=subSubjLen+formCol;;  
                i++;        
            }
            Cell cella=subSubs.createCell(subsubCol);
            cella.setCellStyle(style);
            cella.setCellValue("Description");

            Cell cell1a=subSubs.createCell(subsubCol+1);
            cell1a.setCellStyle(style);
            cell1a.setCellValue("No.of Working Days");

            Cell cell2a=subSubs.createCell(subsubCol+2);
            cell2a.setCellStyle(style);
            cell2a.setCellValue("No.of Present Days");


            List<ExamStudentMarksDisplayStudentsDTO> students=mainDisplayDto.getStudentList();
            /*iterating students*/
            int j=3;
            for(ExamStudentMarksDisplayStudentsDTO stu : students)
            {
                XSSFRow rows=   sheet.createRow(j);
                Cell cell3=rows.createCell(0);
                cell3.setCellStyle(style);
                cell3.setCellValue(stu.getStudentId());
                String lastName="";
                if(stu.getLastMame() !=null)
                {
                    lastName=stu.getLastMame();
                }
                Cell cell4=rows.createCell(1);
                cell4.setCellStyle(style); 
                cell4.setCellValue(stu.getFirstName()+" "+lastName);
                j++;
            }  

            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+mainDisplayDto.getClassName()+""+mainDisplayDto.getExamName()+".xlsx");
            hwb.write(outStream);
            outStream.close();

        }
catch (Exception e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();
}
        return response;
    }
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.location.href="" on an anchor tag or a button element and when the user clicks on it you should call your program where the response returns the excel sheet and downloads on user's downloads folder.

For example:
window.location.href="/downloadExcelMarks"
is url where I'm referring to my controller. Which invokes my controller and I'll be sending the excel in response from my controller as follows:

```
XSSFWorkbook hwb=new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet =  hwb.createSheet("Exam Marks Entry");
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=marks.xlsx");
ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
workbook.write(outStream); // Write workbook to response.
outStream.close();
```

Comment: i am working with spring mvc will it work in spring mvc ?

Comment: Yes for sure. Just put this code inside the controller which you use for downloading. It will work.

Comment: So this request is initiated by the user from browser isn't it?

Comment: yes its an ajax call and i have json object to send with that url

Comment: Thank you @Jai Prakash it worked with some change in my code will post whole answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you can understand that it is browser's property of saving the files to the downloads location. You can set the browser default location of downloads to anywhere in your file system. How can you specify the response to be stored in users system where different users use different file systems.

Comment: Yes its correct . can i just open that excel without saving so that user will save as they want

Comment: If you want the excel data where the user fills data to it, in your application then you should provide an upload option to the users where they can upload the filled Excel sheets and you should parse the excel and read the data.

Comment: user does not fill data they will give class-A as a input and we need to fetch data of class-A and will it with program its all fine but save or open in system in the users system making trouble

Comment: So you were able to download the excel but unable to open it isn't it?

Comment: im not even downloading saving it directly using java